# Jenkinsfile sshScript: how to to run the shell script (sshScript) ssh pipeline steps on remote server with build with paramaters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Wanted to execute the shell script on remote server with user inputs.
my shell script deploy.sh is existed on jenkins workspace.
From jenkins passing the build with paramaters like "version" to shell script.
deploy.sh ${version}
deploy 1.0.0
But getting the java.lang.IllegalArgumentExecption /apps/jenkins/workspace/deploy.sh 1.0.0 does not exists.

```
pipeline {
 agent { label "linux" }
 properties([
     string(description: 'pass the version', name: 'version'}
])
stages {
  stage('shell script to run with paramaters') {
     script {
        def remote = [:]
        remote.name = "hostname"
        remote.user = "username"
        remote.password = "password"
        remote.allowAnyHose = true
        sshScript remote: remote, script: "deploy.sh ${version}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

From the above i am executing the shell script on remote server using the ssh pipeline steps.
I have hardcoded the version in shell script and tried executing from jenkins sshScript. It is successful.
But deploy.sh is failing while i pass the build with paramater "version" (1.0.0) from jenkins.
Where i wanted to run the script dynamically with passing the paramater to the sshScript.

Gettig the below error.
But getting the java.lang.IllegalArgumentExecption /apps/jenkins/workspace/deploy.sh 1.0.0 does not exists.

Also checked that the deploy.sh is on jenkins workspace.

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the ***sshScript*** accepts passing parameters ([reference](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-steps/#plugin-content-sshscript)). What I did was  add the value 1.0.0 to the script and then running it. Or, copy it to the server and run as a sshCommand